# JAVA_HOME : where is java installed

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm trying to set the JAVA_HOME to get tomcat 7 to work with no success.

I'm using CentOS 6.3. Here is what I did so far:

which java
/usr/bin/java

so I edited the .bash_profile, I added

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java

didn't work. I searched online and found another user on stackoverflow who found it in /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/bin/java

I searched on my computer and found that java is located in /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk/bin

I then changed the JAVA_HOME to export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk/bin , tried to start tomcat but server can't be found.

How do I find where java was installed? I didn't install it myself; it was installed during linux installation.

Thanks in advance,
Mike

Comment: How are you trying to start tomcat? Post the error you get.

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` is the directory that contains the `bin` directory, in this case `/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk`.

Comment: I cd into the directory that tomcat was extracted to, then I type bin/startup.sh I was told to start 2 terminals. Type tail -f /server/apache-tomcat-7.0.33/logs/catalina.out in the first one then move the second terminal and type bin/startup.sh   I got this  /server/apache-tomcat-7.0.33/logs/catalina.sh : line 389 : /usr/bin/java/bin/java : Not a directory   I changed JAVA_HOME to export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk, it didn't work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`export JAVA_HOME=/usr` should do it. The script runs `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java`

Comment: Thank you! It finally worked but now I have another problem if I type http://localhost.com:8080 , I get server not found. If I type 127.0.0.1:8080 , the Apache software foundation page displays. This computer isn't connected to the internet.

Comment: Did you mean localhost.com:8080, or localhost:8080?

Comment: that won't work then. localhost.com is not your machine, it's a real domain. You probably want to access localhost:8080

Comment: Yea "localhost.com" is incorrect.  You should use "localhost" or "127.0.0.1".

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if i want it to work locally will all I need to do is set up a dns? I don't care if it's localhost.com or anything else. I'm just curious as to how the setup of .com domain will work.

Comment: You can edit your hosts file (in unix, /etc/hosts) and point any domain you want to 127.0.0.1. Look for the line that points it to localhost, and add somerandomname.com next to localhost.

Answer (score 3):

The strictly correct answer is this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk
```

The issue is that on a typical Linux system you access the `java` command (etc) via symbolic links that are created / managed by the `alternatives` command.  This allows you to make a system-wide choice over which of the java installations should be used by default; i.e. via commands in `/usr/bin`.

The second issue this that the JAVA_HOME environment variable should point at the Java installation directory.  The "bin" directory is a subdirectory of the installation directory.  (Look at the contents of "/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk" !!)

While `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin` will work for locating the commands, it won't work if the Java application needs to find other files in the installation; e.g. the "rt.jar" file.

This "fine distinction" possibly doesn't matter for Tomcat, but it is likely to matter for other Java software that uses the JAVA_HOME convention.

---

Footnote: if you are using an Oracle Java for Linux installation, the default installation directory will be a subdirectory "/usr/java".  Sadly, the Oracle installer doesn't understand that Linux "alternatives" system.  You either have to register the alternatives for each of the Java commands by hand (tedious!!) or add the installation's "bin" directory to your PATH.

Comment: another reason to point to the installation dir rather than bin is that it gives the application the ability to pick up /includes which has files needed for building with the JNI

Answer (score 0):

/usr/bin contains all your binaries; your actual JRE or JVM maybe installed elsewhere so you can run a simple command at /usr/bin to get the actual location of java.

```
ls -lrt
```

A binary may appear like ([soft links](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/soft-hard-links-unixlinux/)):

```
java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/bin/java
```

Okay; now that we know where the java installation is we can now export the JAVA_HOME to one folder above bin i.e /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/
```